# Xpath returning no such element exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to automate a page, basically the task is to extract values from different rows. The table name is same for all the tables moreover the left hand side values in the table are same as well, I need to get the corresponding right hand value, so I am trying to use xpath. Below is the html for couple of tables, but I have 4 more in the page they all have same table ids.

```
     <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="90%" bgcolor="Silver" align="center">
        <tbody><tr>
         <td colspan="3">
         <b>Amos Status&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href=</a>
        </b>
        </td>
         </tr>
               <tr>
               <th>Flow</th>
                <th>Last Processed Message</th>
                <th>Status</th>
              </tr>
                    
            <tr>
            <td>Loopback</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>
              
                <b>On</b>
                
            </td>
             </tr>

                <tr>
            <td>SWIFT</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>
              
                
            <b>On</b>
                
            </td>
              </tr>

                     <tr>
                    <td>CDSX</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>
              
                
                  <b>On</b>
                
                </td>
          </tr>

                <tr>
                 <td>LVTS</td>
                 <td>-</td>
                  <td>
              
                
                  <b>On</b>
                
                </td>
                </tr>

                    
                  <tr>
                  <td>RDMS</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>
                 <b>On</b>
               </td>
                </tr>

                    
                </tbody></table>
                                
                                
        <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="90%" bgcolor="Silver" align="center">
                    <tbody><tr>
        <td colspan="3">
                             <b>Amos Status&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                              <a href="test">Show details</a>
                
                </b>
           </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
             <th>Flow</th>
              <th>Last Processed Message</th>
              <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td>Loopback</td>
                <td>-</td>
                  <td>
              
                
                  <b>On</b>
                
                </td>
          </tr>

             <tr>
                   <td>SWIFT</td>
                   <td>21-02-14 08:28:04</td>
                    <td>
              
                
                  <b>On</b>
                
                
              
            </td>
          </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>CDSX</td>
                 <td>-</td>
                   <td>
              
                
                  <b>On</b>
                
        </td>
          </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>LVTS</td>
                 <td>-</td>
                   <td>
              
                
                  <b>On</b>
                
                
              
            </td>
          </tr>

            <tr>
                       <td>RDMS</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>
              
                
                  <b>On</b>
                
                </td>
          </tr>

                </tbody></table>
```

I need to get the values from the td tag. The following piece of line works for the first tag, For example for Swift I am able to retrieve the value of "-" , now I want to get the value from the second SWIFT td tag (the date), but I get a no such element exception message.

```
 WebElement getData = driver.findElement(
   By.xpath("//tr[td='SWIFT'][1]/td[2]"));
WebElement getData1 = driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//tr//td[contains(text(),'SWIFT')]/following-sibling::td[2]"));
```

The above two statement give me a value of "-" which is correct but as soon as I change it to the following, In order to get the date value,  I get a no such element exception error.

```
 WebElement getData = driver.findElement(
   By.xpath("//tr[td='SWIFT'][2]/td[2]"));

WebElement getData1 = driver.findElement(
   By.xpath("//tr//td[contains(text(),'SWIFT')][2]/following-sibling::td[2]"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using the following statement.

```
By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'SWIFT')]/following-sibling::td")
```

Saving all the values of Swift's following sibling in an array using the following.

```
 List<WebElement> getNextRowData = _getDriver()
  .findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'SWIFT')]/following-sibling::td"));
   List<String> depths = new ArrayList<>();
   for (WebElement rowData : getNextRowData) {
   depths.add(rowData.getText());
}
```